# I am trying to copy the fax number from account to opportunity

Tags: trigger

I am trying to copy the fax number from account to opportunity (** and opportunity always related to or populated to account fax)

```
//When new opportunity is created then the Opportunity fax field is updated,populate a custom field from a related account.
trigger faxCAccountFromOppty on Opportunity (before insert,before update) {
// List<ID,String> listfax = new List<ID,String>();
    for(Account faxAcc : [Select id,fax  from account where fax <> null])
    {
        If(faxAcc.id !=null)
        {
            for(Opportunity faxOppty: new trigger){
                faxOppty.id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need it to be indexed, just use a formula field (Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Fields > Custom Fields). The formula would be:

```
Account.Fax
```

As a bonus, the fax would always be correct, even if it changes on the account.

Alternatively, you could also do this through a workflow rule (via Field Update), or by Process Builder. Neither of these technologies require writing any code at all.

However, to answer the original question, if you wanted to do this through a trigger, you'll use the standard Aggregate-Query-Update pattern:

```
trigger copyFaxToOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    // Aggregate
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        accounts.put(record.AccountId, null);
    }
    // Query
    accounts.putAll([SELECT Fax FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accounts.keySet()]);
    // Update
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        if(accounts.get(record.AccountId) != null) {
             record.Fax__c = accounts.get(record.AccountId).Fax;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: accounts.put(record.AccountId); ( map doesn't exist ).. still it is showing the error

Comment: @user28787 I do that pretty much every time... there should be a null second parameter. I've updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: trigger AccFaxToOppFax on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    String faxdata;
    for(Account a : [Select Id, fax from account where fax != null]){
        faxdata = a.fax;
        for(Opportunity opp: trigger.new){
            if(a.id == opp.accountid && Opp.fax__c == null){
            opp.fax__c = faxdata;
            }
    
        }
        
        
    }
}

Comment: please check above code

Comment: @user28787 Again, you need to use an aggregate-query-update pattern, using a map, and filtering your query just to include records that are in the trigger. Your code will break as soon as  you reach 50,000 accounts that have a fax number, assuming it doesn't break sooner because of CPU time limits.